# Prove the Total Mechanical Energy of the System is Conserved via Differential Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, conservation-laws, differentiation

Consider the dynamics of a particle P shown: [Particle in 3D space with Radius r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLcqv.png)
Newton's second law states that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}(m\dot r) = \mathbf F$$

where, $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the position vector of the particle, $\boldsymbol{\dot r}$  is its velocity vector and $m$ is its mass. $\mathbf F$ is the total external force (vector) acting on P. **Prove the following result regarding the existent of mechanical energy integral of motion of the system:**

*Theorem: For the dynamical system, if $F = -\nabla V (\boldsymbol{r}) $ i.e the force, $\mathbf F$, is the negative gradient of a scalar function $V(\mathbf r)$ of only the position vector, then the total mechanical energy of the system is conserved. Moreover, the function $V(\mathbf r)$ is nothing but the potential energy of the system.*

Hints:

The above theorem states that if  $F = -\nabla V (\boldsymbol{r}) $ then the mechanical energy is an integral of motion.

The gradient of a scalar function, $V$ is written as:

$\nabla V = \partial V / \partial \boldsymbol{r} $

Also, the gradient of a scalar quantity is a vector. *Do not worry about writing it in terms of the components*

Recall the mechanical energy is the sum of KE and PE. Mechanical energy is given by the standard form:

$$T=1/2 ∗ m\boldsymbol{\dot r} \cdot \boldsymbol{\dot r} $$

where $\boldsymbol{\dot r} \cdot \boldsymbol{\dot r}$ represents the dot product of $\boldsymbol{\dot r} $, which is the velocity vector, with itself (i.e. square of the speed: $\boldsymbol{\dot r} \cdot \boldsymbol{\dot r} = v^2$ )

Also, let $G = G(\mathbf r, t)$  be a scalar function of a vector, $r$, and a scalar, $t$. Then, the total derivative of $G$ is related to its partial derivatives by:

$$dG = \frac{\partial G}{ \boldsymbol{\partial r}}\cdot d\mathbf r + \frac{\partial G}{\partial t}\cdot dt$$

with $\frac{\partial G}{ \boldsymbol{\partial r}} $  identified as the gradient of G, which is a vector quantity, and $\frac{\partial G}{ \boldsymbol{\partial r}}\cdot d\mathbf r $  as the dot product between the gradient of $G$ and $d\boldsymbol{r}$

Do not assume that $V(\boldsymbol{r})$ is the potential energy as this should be a natural conclusion of the analysis.

To begin, take the time derivative of the kinetic energy. Recall that if $c = \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} $ is the dot product of two vectors, then the time derivative of c is:
$$\dot c = \boldsymbol{\dot a} \cdot \boldsymbol{b} + \boldsymbol{a} \cdot \boldsymbol{\dot b}$$

ASSUME THE PARTICLE'S MASS, $m$ is constant

Edit:
Attempted solution:
$$\frac {d}{dt}(m \dot r) = F $$
$$\frac {d}{dr}(m \dot r)\frac {dr}{dt} = F$$
$$d(mv)v = Fdr$$
$$\int mvdv = \int Fdr$$
$$\frac {1}{2}mv^2 + \int-Fdr = C $$

Seems to prove the above theorem, however this kind of seems to ignore the fact that the variables are vectors. How can a similar approach be applied to the vectors? And still derive the potential energy at the end?

Basically, I'm asking how the potential energy can be an outcome of $$\frac {d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2} m \dot r \cdot \dot r) $$
and
$$\frac{d}{dt}(m\dot r) = \mathbf F$$

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Please note that this type of "solve this problem for me" question is off topic as per the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).   If there is some aspect of this question giving you trouble, try to ask a conceptual physics question, and show any relevant work.

Comment: ^question edited to hopefully address the concerns of @JMac

Comment: Why are you bolding some vectors and not others? $r$ and $\mathbf{r}$ are completely different things.

Comment: In $dG$, where did $c$ come from and what is it?

Comment: I modified the equations to depict vectors and scalars appropriately (I am somewhat new to latex), the c in $dG$ is simply the constant $t$, which I changed to be more clear

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $\dot r$:

$m \ddot r \dot r = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2}m \dot r^{2})$

$-\frac{\partial V } {\partial r} \frac{\partial r} {\partial t} = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working in radial coordinates(which may be tricky because the unit vectors change  with respect to time), I would suggest seeing the x,y,z equations of motion separately. So you have,
$$m \ddot{x}= -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}, \hspace{0.5mm}m \ddot{y}= -\frac{\partial V}{\partial y}, \hspace{0.5mm}m \ddot{z}= -\frac{\partial V}{\partial z}. $$
Now add these three equations and check for yourself that the following and the equations above imply the same thing i.e., $$\frac{d\Big(\frac{1}{2}m(\dot{x}^2 +\dot{y}^2+\dot{z}^2)+V(r)\Big)}{dt}=0. $$
So in some sense you could have integrated the equations of motion to get this.